# Frame of self.view is not consistent between iOS6 and iOS7

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7, frame

In my App, the `frame` of `self.view` is usually used to located it's child views. But the problem is `self.view.frame` is not consistent between iOS6 and iOS7. The translucent option of the navigation bar is disabled in storybaord. Testing in Xcode5 with 4 inch retina iPhone simulator.

How can we make the `self.view.frame` be the same in iOS6 and iOS7? Any help will be appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
    NSLog(@"self.view in viewDidLoad:%@",self.view);
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"self.view in viewWillAppear:%@",self.view);
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"self.view in viewDidAppear: %@",self.view);
}
```

Log in iOS7:

```
2013-09-30 14:01:31.584 TestViewFrame[10088:a0b] self.view in viewDidLoad:<UIView: 0xa127b10; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa127bb0>>
2013-09-30 14:01:31.587 TestViewFrame[10088:a0b] self.view in viewWillAppear:<UIView: 0xa127b10; frame = (0 64; 320 504); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa127bb0>>
2013-09-30 14:01:31.591 TestViewFrame[10088:a0b] self.view in viewDidAppear: <UIView: 0xa127b10; frame = (0 64; 320 504); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xa127bb0>>
```

Log in iOS6:

```
2013-09-30 14:12:32.505 TestViewFrame[10167:c07] self.view in viewDidLoad:<UIView: 0x8158390; frame = (0 20; 320 548); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x81589a0>>
2013-09-30 14:12:32.508 TestViewFrame[10167:c07] self.view in viewWillAppear:<UIView: 0x8158390; frame = (0 0; 320 504); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x81589a0>>
2013-09-30 14:12:32.521 TestViewFrame[10167:c07] self.view in viewDidAppear: <UIView: 0x8158390; frame = (0 0; 320 504); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x81589a0>>
```